# Javascript switch statement only triggering first case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

a[2] is a random integer variable from 1 - 100. When it is less than than 33 it changes to red but when it is above 33 it stays black. Anyone got an idea why it ignores the last 2 cases?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  switch (a[2]) {
    case < 33:
      document.getElementByID('speechstat').style.color = "red";
      break;

    case >= 33 && <= 66:
      document.getElementByID('speechstat').style.color = "blue";
      break;

    case > 66:
      document.getElementByID('speechstat').style.color = "green";
      break;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try looking up the [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) of how to use `switch`?

Comment: [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). Spelling matters. Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, you can't compare a variable with `switch` but you can do so indirectly as this post's answer shows: [switch statement to compare values greater or less than a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576618/switch-statement-to-compare-values-greater-or-less-than-a-number/32576647)

With a few edits and adding some html to check if everything works this is how you would do this in your case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="speechstat1"></p>
<p id="speechstat2"></p>
<p id="speechstat3"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 34; //You can set this to whatever you want or a user's input
    switch (true) {

        case (a<33):
            document.getElementById("speechstat1").innerHTML = "red works";
            break;

        case a>= 33 && a<= 66:
            document.getElementById('speechstat2').innerHTML = "blue works";
            break;

        case a> 66:
            document.getElementById("speechstat3").innerHTML = "green works";
            break;          
    }

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- I put in `.innerHTML` just to show it works, in your case you can replace those 
  lines with whatever you want to make happen.
- I changed `Switch` to `switch`
- I changed `.getElementByID` to `.getElementById` Spelling matters!
- If you are testing a variable for two conditions: `case >= 33  <= 66:` you 
  need to add the "and" operator `case >= 33 **&&** <= 66:`
- I changed `a[2]` to `a` so it doesn't error out because it's not named 
  correctly

Overall it's easier to use if and else statements for something like this as Morgan Wilde mentioned.

Comment: @user10421273 if this answer helped you, please consider upvoting it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, switch statements look differently than what you've posted. For example, here's some [documentation on `switch` statements on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

If you want to check for ranges, you should check with regular `if/else` statements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var color;

    // Check the possible value ranges.
    if (a[2] < 33) { color = 'red'; }
    else if (a[2] >= 33 && a[2] <= 66) { color = 'blue'; }
    else if (a[2] > 66) { color = 'green'; }

    document.getElementByID('speechstat').style.color = color;
</script>
```