# Different results between if statement and Switch in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm running two seemingly identical statements to check whether a number is positive, negative or zero.

The `if` statement returns the expected result.

The `switch` statement always returns the default.

Why?

In this example I pass "`2`" (`type: number`) and I get `+` in the `if` statement and `?` in the `switch` statement.

```js
// Verify whether a number is positive, negative or Zero:

function myFuncIf(y) {
  let result = null;
  console.log("y is " + y);
  console.log("y is " + typeof(y));

  if (y > 0) {
    return "+";
  } else if (y < 0) {
    return "-";
  } else {
    return "?";
  }
}

function myFuncSwitch(y) {
  let result = null;
  console.log("y is " + y);
  console.log("y is " + typeof(y));

  switch (y) {
    case (y > 0):
      result = "+";
      break;
    case (y < 0):
      result = "-";
      break;
    default:
      result = "?";
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(myFuncIf(2));
console.log(myFuncSwitch(2));
```

Comment: That's not how the `switch ... case ...` statement works: _"The `switch` statement **evaluates an expression, matching the expression's value to a `case` clause**, and executes statements associated with that case, as well as statements in cases that follow the matching case."_ ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [switch statement to compare values greater or less than a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32576618/1220550)

Answer (score 1):

`switch` matches the *value*.
The value of `y` is `2`.
Your first `case` will match `True`.
Your second will match `False`.

You probably want your switch to look like this:

```
  switch (Math.sign(y)) {
    case (1):
      result = "+";
      break;
    case (-1):
      result = "-";
      break;
    default:
      result = "?";
  }
```

See docs here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign

Comment: But the return value is "?" although clearly 2 is bigger than 0..

Comment: The value of `2` does not equal `True` and does not equal `False` so it falls through to the `default` case.