# Switch statement within function returns "undefined" for no obvious reason

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement, return

I am trying to create a simplistic function which uses a switch statement to return a weighted number. For my use case, the solution is most befitting, however I am getting "undefined" as the result for no obvious reasons. If anyone could point out the mistake, I'm making.

```js
function randomCase() {
  let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

  switch (n) {
    case n < 70:
      return 1;
    case n < 80:
      return 2;
    case n < 90:
      return 3;
    case n < 100:
      return 4;
  }
}

temp = randomCase();

console.log(temp);
```

I tried to debug with Chrome developer tool and figure out what might be causing this, but of no avail. It seems there is something obvious I'm missing. (Still learning JS)

Comment: Please review how a `switch` statement is to be structured: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch the `n` in `switch(n)` should *be equal* to one of the cases for the case to trigger. However, a number is not equal to one of the booleans that a comparison produces.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Isn't the case for n enough to trigger the return.

Comment: `switch(x) { case y: /*...*/` is going to be the same as `if (x === y)`. With your `switch(n) { case n < 70: /*...*/` that will be the same as `if (n === (n < 70))`. So, no - it won't work. Because that's not how `switch` statements work.

Comment: change `switch (n)` to `switch (true)` and you'll be good to go

Answer (score 1):

As VLAZ mentioned in the comments, a switch statement checks for equality.

You'll want to use an if statement instead:

```js
function randomCase() {
  let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

  if (n < 70) {
    return 1;
  } else if (n < 80) {
    return 2;
  } else if (n < 90) {
      return 3;
  } else if (n < 100) {
      return 4;
  }
}

temp = randomCase();

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: Thanks for you explanations. I found my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576618/switch-statement-to-compare-values-greater-or-less-than-a-number