# Switch function - value between two numbers

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I dont understand why my function doesnt take the value 70.

```
let test = (age) => {
  switch (age) {
    case (age > 65):
      console.log("High age")
      break
    default:
      console.log("Low age")
      break
  }
}

test(70)
```

Comment: That's simply not how switch statements work. `age > 65` is evaluated to either `true` or `false`, neither of which is equal to `age` itself. You _could_ do `switch (age > 65)` then make the cases the booleans, but as below just _use a regular condition_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch statement for greater-than/less-than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665997/switch-statement-for-greater-than-less-than)

Comment: or [switch statement to compare values greater or less than a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576618/switch-statement-to-compare-values-greater-or-less-than-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

To use a switch statement, you could modify your code like this:

```
let test = (age) => {
  switch (age) {
    case 65:
    case 66:
    case 67:
    case 68:
    case 69:
    case 70:
      console.log("High age");
      break;
    default:
      console.log("Low age");
      break;
  }
}

test(70);
```

Comment: While this does switch on `age`, I would definitely recommend against this approach for obvious reasons. Just use the `>` operator (or similar) in e.g. an if-else statement.